# Django - What's the most secure way to pass parameters?

Tags: django, function, session, view

I'm working on an app that handles some sensitive information (API keys, etc). I have a simple question that I cannot find answers to. I have an encrypt function implemented as to not store the data in plain text.

Should I be passing the variables back and forth to encrypt/decrypt between functions using return, or using request.session? They both tend to work, but what's more secure? Would it be more secure to call the function and handle the return since that would only process on the backend, or should I use session variables?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
  window.history.replaceState('','','/');
</script>
```

Try this for secure instead `/` you can use you URL

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33296997)